# Serving a single compiled typescript bundle for browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I am having problems building a typescript workflow. I have bunch of typescript files. I would like them to be compiled and concatenated into a single bundle. I would like this bundle to be served to web browsers. However, browser doesn't recognize some of the outputted keywords (export, exports, define, system).

After some research, I have came up with requireJs.

Here is my structure:

```
dist
    |__js
        |__dist.js //The compiled bundle will reside here.
    |__index.html
    |__main.js // For require JS.
src
    |__configuration.ts
    |__core.ts
    |__info-card.ts
    |__main.ts
    |__pack.ts
gulpfile.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

The `tsconfig.json` file has the following rules:

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/*.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile": "dist.js"
    }
}
```

The colpiled `dist.js` output is as follows:

```
define("configuration", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Configuration = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Configuration(drawArea, size, className, sidePadding, marginBetweenPacks, lineColor) {
            this.className = "info-card";
            this.sidePadding = 20;
            this.marginBetweenPacks = 50;
            this.lineColor = "#777";
            this.drawArea = drawArea;
            this.size = size;
        }
        return Configuration;
    }());
    exports.Configuration = Configuration;
    var Size = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Size() {
        }
        return Size;
    }());
    exports.Size = Size;
});
define("info-card", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var InfoCard = /** @class */ (function () {
        function InfoCard() {
        }
        return InfoCard;
    }());
    exports.InfoCard = InfoCard;
    var Connection = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Connection() {
        }
        return Connection;
    }());
    exports.Connection = Connection;
});
define("pack", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Pack = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Pack() {
        }
        return Pack;
    }());
    exports.Pack = Pack;
});
define("core", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var SankeyGraph = /** @class */ (function () {
        function SankeyGraph(config, packs) {
            this.configuration = config;
            this.packs = packs;
            this.prepare();
        }
        SankeyGraph.prototype.draw = function () {
        };
        SankeyGraph.prototype.prepare = function () {
            var scrollableContent = this.prepareScrollableContent();
            this.canvasElement = this.prepareCanvasElement();
            this.infocardContainer = this.prepareInfocardContainer();
            scrollableContent.appendChild(this.canvasElement);
            scrollableContent.appendChild(this.infocardContainer);
            this.configuration.drawArea.appendChild(scrollableContent);
            this.calculateColumnWidth();
        };
        SankeyGraph.prototype.prepareScrollableContent = function () {
            var content = document.createElement("div");
            content.style.overflowY = "auto";
            content.style.overflowX = "hidden";
            content.style.width = this.configuration.size.width + "px";
            content.style.height = this.configuration.size.height + "px";
            content.style.position = "absolute";
            return content;
        };
        SankeyGraph.prototype.prepareCanvasElement = function () {
            var element = document.createElement("div");
            element.style.width = this.configuration.size.width + "px";
            element.style.position = "absolute";
            element.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
            return element;
        };
        SankeyGraph.prototype.prepareInfocardContainer = function () {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            container.style.width = this.configuration.size.width + "px";
            container.style.height = this.configuration.size.height + "px";
            container.style.position = "absolute";
            return container;
        };
        SankeyGraph.prototype.getColumnCount = function () {
            var columnNumber = 1;
            this.packs.forEach(function (pack, packIndex) {
                pack.infoCards.forEach(function (infoCard, infoCardIndex) {
                    if (columnNumber <= infoCard.column)
                        columnNumber = infoCard.column;
                });
            });
            this.columnCount = columnNumber;
        };
        SankeyGraph.prototype.calculateColumnWidth = function () {
            this.columnWidth = Math.floor(this.configuration.drawArea.offsetWidth / this.columnCount);
        };
        return SankeyGraph;
    }());
    exports.SankeyGraph = SankeyGraph;
});
define("main", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Lö Text"));
});
```

What I eventually want is that I can put this `dist.js` file into browser, and simply "works". Such as, I would like to instantiate new `SankeyGraph` instances at will.

To do this, I have made some requireJS configurations in `dist/main.js`. The content as follows:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "./",
    paths: {
        "App": "./js/dist"
    }
});

requirejs(["App"], function(App) {
    console.log(App);
});
```

Sorry for the too much code, I didn't know how to simplify but also giving enough information. This is the HTML file content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script data-main="./main" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `console.log(App)` outputs undefined in the browser. Please point me to the right direction, with simplest possible solution. I have an another project with pure JS and I would like to use this one's compiled output with that one.

Comment: if you use modules  in your code you will need a module loader to load the code. requirejs or systemjs do fine. if you don't want to use modules you can switch to namespace, it's typescript's way to do IIFE like modules without a module loader.

Comment: @toskv Namespaces did the trick. Actually, it was the <reference path="..." /> element what did the trick. Thanks for pointing out. If you can post an answer, I would mark it as solved.

Comment: I think it might be a duplicate of a question I answered a while ago. :)